# The data is lost from the project after i import it in to eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I accidentally deleted a completed project of mine from eclipse. The deleted project is still in my workspace folder. I tried to import it in to eclipse by clicking, File -> Android -> Existing android code in to workspace. I had checked my data in the project folder, before importing it in to eclipse by opening it in notepad. The data was all there then. But after i opened it in eclipse, the data is all lost. The java files and xml files are there, but with no codes inside. It is all 0kb. Is there any solution to recover it back ?

Comment: I suggest to move the project folder **AWAY** (to another path) from the workspace and import it from the new path. Otherwise, you're doing a circular reference (it tries to write in the workspace what it's importing from the same place).

Comment: I had tried with same. I had placed the folder in another path (not the workspace). And tried to import it in eclipse using File -> Import -> General -> Existing projects in to workspace. I selected the path of my project which is currently residing in another path in the "Select root directory". But the problem is the "Next" or "Finish" button is inactivate there.

Comment: You have to erase everything that refers to the old project, in Eclipse and on the filesystem. Only leave the project copied in the other path and import it from there (in Windows you can simply copy the patch from the file manager and paste it into the import window). Select "Copy projects into workspace"

Comment: Try right clicking on the project and select `Restore from Local History` to see if Eclipse has a copy of the project file in its history.

Comment: I just can't open that project in eclipse. I had erased that projected from the workspace and pasted that in another path. Even then i am not able to open it in eclipse. The project is not showing in the "Projects" field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easiest way..

start a new workspace and do an android project import of the project form your first workspace.

In future yo should get use to the git dev flow which would be to set up the project in another folder rather than the eclipse workspace..other benefit is that whenever you update Eclipse versions workspace etc you still have a non corrupted subfolder with all your pojrects in it.

Comment: I did the same. I have learnt a lot from the careless mistake that i made. When a project gets deleted by mistake, we shouldn't close the eclipse. We can recover the lost project by undoing it by clicking Edit -> Undo. Or by just importing it in a correct way. File-> Import-> General -> Existing Project in to Workspace. The mistake i made is i clicked, Import -> Android -> Existing android code into workspace. And that's how i lost my data.